# Can opencv get last frame from living streaming?

Tags: python, opencv, rtmp, live-streaming

I have many rtmp streaming, and I want to save a jpg every 5s.

At first, I use ffmpeg, but every time I get the picture, ffmpeg will close the rtmp connection. and I can't get a picture in 5s.

Then I find opencv , and I open each streaming, read picture, but, every time I read , I get next frame, So I can't get 'now' frame.

Is there any way to get last frame from living streaming use opencv by python?

Sorry about my poor English.